# how to use scroll viewer with wrap panel in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a button when I click the Button. I create buttons dynamically and add button to wrap panel and show it in window but if button goes beyond the width. I want to scroll if I use wrap panel inside scroll viewer when in click the button wrap panel doesn't show.

Comment: Please see the [ask] section for instruction on how to ask a question. Your question is more likely to be answered if you can provide a sample code in a working condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base your solution upon this :

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width ="100" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="76,0,113,213">
   <WrapPanel>
        <Button Content="Press" />
        <Button Content="Press" />
        <Button Content="Press" />
        <Button Content="Press" />
        <Button Content="Press" />
        <Button Content="Press" />
    </WrapPanel>
 </ScrollViewer>
```